# Is there a way to edit a channel for each user who reacts to embed message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently having an issue with editing channel permissions for each member who reacts to an embed.

The current code I have is:

`channel.createOverwrite([{ id: user.id, allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'] }])`

This does allow the user to view the channel but it only changes the channel permissions once.

So for example:

User 1 clicks the embed reaction which allows them for the channel.
User 2 then reacts to the embed which removes User 1 from being able to view the channel and adds user 2.

I want both users to be allowed to view the channel once the reaction has been clicked but just can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was creating a bug-reporting system (using a ticketing-type system) for my own discord bot, I faced the exact same issue and realized that I couldn't use `channel.createOverwrite()` because it overrides any and all permissions that were previously setup for the channel (including the overwrites created for other users, as well as the overwrites that prevented everyone from sending messages in my bug-reports channel).

My solution was to first fetch all of the current overwrites for the channel, and then simply append the overwrites for the user that reacted onto them. It's possible that there might be a simpler method of doing this; but my solution is tested and worked for me, so that's what I'm including in this answer. Here's an example, based on the code from my bot and modified to suit your purpose.

**Giving the user(s) perms to view the channel**

```
//Fetch current channel permission overwrites
var overwrites = channel.permissionOverwrites.array();

//If overwrite already exists for reacting user, address it (to prevent dupe overwrites)
if (overwrites.find(o => o.id == user.id)) return;

//Add the overwrite for the user that reacted
overwrites.push({
    id: user.id,
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
})

//Give permissions to view channel
channel.overwritePermissions(overwrites, 'Add reason for allowing user to view channel here');
```

**Removing the user(s) perms to view the channel**

```
//Fetch current channel permission overwrites
var overwrites = channel.permissionOverwrites.array();

//Remove the user's perms to send messages in channel
overwrites.splice(overwrites.findIndex(o => o.id == user.id), 1);
message.channel.overwritePermissions(overwrites, 'Reason');
```

**Explanation**

So in both examples, we first get all of the current permission overwrites in the channel (including the permissions set for both roles and users in that channel).

When giving the user perms, we then check to see if the user already has an overwrite in the channel and if so, return (assuming the only overwrites they will be getting in this channel are the `VIEW_CHANNEL` perms they receive from this bot; otherwise, change the `return` to something else that suits your purposes). Then, we add in a new overwrite created for our reacting user, and replace all of the channel's permission overwrites with our newly modified version; this allows us to include both the overwrite for the user that just reacted as well as the overwrites for all of the users that have already reacted.

When removing the user's perms to view the channel, we simply use `.splice()` to remove the overwrite's index from the array of overwrites, and then we update the channel's overwrites with our newly modified version.

If you find a simpler way of achieving this at any point in time, feel free to comment it below and I will append it to this answer.

**Relevant Resources**

[Discord.js docs for channel.overwritePermissions()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) 
[A working example in my discord bot](https://github.com/Cannicide/zh-bot/blob/master/commands/report.js#L250)